# How to understand the format of keypoints and des in Orb ouput in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

The  output of orb in cv2 library has the keypoints part and the descriptor part as the following:
    KeyPoint 0x7ff805343060 ---> this is for keypoint taken just one to show.

```
[[124 163 154 ..., 206 142   2]
 [  3 183  47 ...,   0 187 197]
 [184   7 243 ..., 226 118 169]
 ..., 
 [218  12 190 ..., 100  47  78]
 [214 248 170 ...,  35 175  83]
 [242  72 226 ..., 184 126 142]] ----> this is  descriptor part.
```

Could you please explain me the format of these data. And also, extract information about the spatial location of the keypoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORB gives 32 Bytes descriptor for each keypoint as an output ranging from 0 to 255.

Which is a 256 bit value (32*8 bits).

The bit values are the comparision of intensity values in a patch and are composed with 1 and 0.